# How to login a Webpage and retrieve data to a Java Application?

Tags: java, authentication, wimax

I want to make an app for my own using. To show the wimax signals,
CINR, Upload Speed etc. When the device connects, open the browser
`http://192.168.2.1` , after login (javascript login paage) it shows the
values.

I want to get those data to my apps. So, how can I do that?
Any example?

[image: Image of Info's]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use a library like Jsoup to parse the HTML data.

I'm assuming this is a router you're trying to access, which normally uses [basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). You'll also need a library to do base64 encoding for basic authentication, such as Apache commons.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

...

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String username = "username";
    String password = "password";
    String login = username + ":" + password;
    String base64login = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(login.getBytes()));

    Document document = Jsoup
        .connect("http://192.168.2.1")
        .header("Authorization", "Basic " + base64login)
        .get();

    Element e = document.select("body");
    ...
    /* Select the elements and HTML text you're interested here */
}
```

That should be enough to get you started. You can learn more about how to use Jsoup [here](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)